# How to setup a taxonomy that can have only one post assigned to it?

Tags: customization, taxonomy

I have a Custom Taxonomy of, "Show on Front Page". I would like only one post to be assigned to this. So if I went and created an new post and checked the "Show on Front Page", the previous post that had that checked would no longer be associated with that Custom Taxonomy.

Is this possible?

Comment: Instead of a taxonomy you should just use a variable and assign the post id to that variable. So what ever post id is assigned to the variable can then be shown on the front end. In my opinion, taxonomy is not for what you want to do.

Comment: Can you offer an example?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to force an implementation as you've described it, doesn't it make more sense to change the WP_Query on the front page, to only show one post, regardless of how many posts are in the given taxonomy term?

Comment: That's actually exactly how I have it setup. It pulls from that tax and the most recent one. This is a request from the boss to cut down on confusion in the backend for the client. You know, if they see more than one "front page"